# Extract an image (blob) from database and insert it in a frame Java

Tags: java, mysql, swing

I have a db with a table "Images" with a field "Img" which contains image (type BLOB).

I extract an image with a query sql like this :

```
select img from images where id = 1
```

In a java swing project how can I obtain the image result of this query ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work

```
Blob blob = rs.getBlob("img");
int blobLength = (int) blob.length();  

byte[] bytes = blob.getBytes(1, blobLength);
blob.free();
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
```

You have options with how you want to add it the the frame. You can add it an a `JLabel` or you can paint it on a `JPanel`. Just depends on your requirements and/or preferences.

- To use `JLabel`

  ```
  ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(bytes); // you can read straight from byte array
  JLabel label = new JLabel(icon);
  frame.add(label);
  ```
- To paint on `JPanel`

  ```
  @Override
  protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this); 
      // img is the BufferedImage in the first code.
  }
  ```